# Query all paths in all packages/repos without installing?

Tags: yum

Let's say I want to create a new package that installs a command, i.e. adds a new file to /bin or /usr/bin.

But I have yet to name the command.  So if I'm to run into conflicts, I want to find out ASAP.

So given that I have a few repos (Fedora, RPM fusion...), is there a query to help me verify that a particular file/command would not be installed by any other package currently available?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not go the route of just checking fedora, because then you run into a problem when you want to package it somewhere else, or fedora brings in an existing app who's moniker collides with yours.

I have had a distro packager force me to change the (short, snappy) name of a command in an app I wrote when it went into official repos, because it collided with some ancient, but still available cruft.  You might as well get it right now.

Start with a reasonably unique name and **search the net** using a search engine (or two). Also search *at least* [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/) and [github](https://github.com/) directly.  Even if something appears to target a completely different OS (windows, IOS, etc), avoid the collision.

If you cannot search the net using just the command name (i.e., do not search "linux mycommandname") because it returns too much unrelated whatever, then the word is not unique enough (this includes words that turn out to exist in a foriegn language, brand names of pop from Australia, etc). This probably means at least 5 characters; less than that at this point is just begging for coincidence, and more is probably better.  It is better to use a long, descriptive name for a command (`superFooBar`) and let people create their own short alias (`foo`) if they want than to create a short near meaningless one (acronyms, words with vowels removed, etc.).  This is not going into POSIX any time soon, it's an obscure, optional application and should be labelled for clarity and not convenience.

---

If all you want to do is search the repos available on a particular system, you can use `yum provides`:

```
yum provides "*/superFooBar"
```

Note the quotes with a glob star inside; this prevents shell expansion it so it will be passed literally to `yum`, which treats it as a wildcard in the same way.  This will search the full path of all files installed by all packages in all repos, so matches might include `/usr/bin/superFooBar`, `/etc/default/superFooBar` etc.

Again, I recommend against this if you have any intention of distributing this publicly, or privately within an organization.  If it's just for you and machines you have some personal responsibility for, fine -- otherwise it is not thorough enough.

Comment: Sorry but I don't think you're answering the question.  you are giving good but general advice.

Comment: @AloisMahdal True, I'm not answering the question in the title -- but I am answering the question in the body.  Perhaps there is an implied [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: In fact, my general strategy is to verify it for Fedora (+rpmfusion) and Debian, and maybe then ask on other channels.  The Debian part can be done by their (awesome) web search facilities.  The Fedora part seems harder since there are usually more repos, so I was wondering if there are some yum super-powers to use.

Comment: You might want to clarify that in the question by saying you want to search *all* (official) fedora repos (official doesn't include rpmfusion, I think) and include the parallel to the debian online search.  Currently it reads as if you want to search all repos configured on a given system. I don't think you can configure all existing repos on one system because some of them would conflict, but maybe you can.  If not, you obviously need some kind of separate system (e.g, a web search), which is why I said "official" as such a thing would most likely be delimited along some such line.

Comment: *as if you want to search all repos configured on a given system* - yes, that's exactly what I want :) *configure all existing repos on one system* no I don't want that;  I have a "sane" set of repos.  OTOH, see: if the repos conflict among themselves (e.g. in commands), it does not actually break the scenario for me.

Comment: Okay, I've added a few paragraphs at the end detailing one simple approach to that.

Comment: Honestly I think your answer could be just that one line: "use `yum provides`" and I'd still accept it as perfectly fine answer.  While I appreciate the will to help, you seem to assume lack of other experience or research on part of poster/reader.  For those like me who are already fairly experienced in world of FOSS/distros/bash/... and are just missing *the yum command*, 90% of the rest is mostly distraction.

Comment: *Again, I recommend against this* why would you?  Well it could be very unwise to use it as the only safeguard but why would you *recommend against*?

Comment: Yeah, the "it is not thorough enough" was to point out that doing *just* that is, well, not thorough enough.  I've actually gotten bitten twice this way.  There is an unimaginable amount of totally obscure stuff that for whatever reason ends up in repos.  That's why I wanted to stress using a long descriptive name instead of a short snappy one, and doing a net search.  If you search for the exact word and get "No results found.", that's a good sign.  But of course the more you do the better.  Search upstream hosting sites (sourceforge, etc.), search repos, etc., absolutely --

Comment: -- but don't do that because you just really really want to lay claim to `foo`.  Use `superFooBar` (actually that already has web sites, you may want to avoid collision with those too).